# haskell foldr and variable

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, fold

How can I make a function similar to this but with `n` being a variable with a number beginning in `1` and ending with the value of the length of xs?

For Example I want `[1,2,3]` to return the result of `3*1 + 2*2 + 1*3`.

```
function :: [Int] -> Int
function xs = foldr (\x acc -> (x*n) + acc) 0 xs
```

Answer (score 9):

A idiomatic Haskell answer can be:

```
function = sum . zipWith (*) [1 ..] . reverse
```

Reading from right to left: you reverse the list (`reverse`), doing so you won't need to count backward (from n to 1) but forward (1 to n)... then you zip it with the index using * (`zipWith (*) [1..]`) and finally sou sum things up (`sum`).

Comment: Is it possible that Rance wanted a less general solution, like this: "function n = sum . zipWith (*) [1 .. ] . reverse $ take n [1 ..]" ?

Comment: According to the signature he gave for `function`, I don't think so.

Comment: btw, it's easier to write `[1 .. n]` rathern than `take n [1 ..]` ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using `zipWith`:

```
import Data.List

function :: [Int] -> Int
function xs = sum $ zipWith (*) xs lst
              where
                lst = unfoldr (\x -> Just (x-1,x-1)) $ (length xs) + 1

main = putStr $ show $ function [40,50,60]
```

Comment: If I understand the question right, `function [40,50,60]` should result in `3*40 + 2*50 + 1*60`, and not in `60*40+50*50+40*60`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function xs = fst $ foldr (\x (acc,n) -> (x*n+acc,n+1)) (0,1) xs
```

Or maybe more readable:

```
function = fst . foldr f (0,1) where f x (acc,n) = (x*n+acc, n+1)
```